# MATLAB R2022b cannot load .nii.gz (compressed neuroimaging) data

Tags: matlab, path, mri

I've been trying to open compressed fMRI data (.nii.gz file) on MATLAB, using the **load_nifti** function.

EDIT-> I had initially tried to use the **load_nii** function, but MATLAB did not recognize this command and itself suggested using the **load_nifti** command instead. My version of MATLAB has not 3rd party toolboxes or apps installed - the **load_nifti** (formerly **load_nii** function) have been integrated within the image processing toolbox since R2017b.

I am using MATLAB on LINUX Ubuntu version 22

Since there are many subjects, I've made a root path function in order to access this data.

```
root_path = ['/media/megan2/VERBATIM HD/dHCP_data/sub-' subj '/' 'ses-' ses_id '/' task];
```

Where `subj` and `ses_id` are variables that change.

The workspace has the list of `subj` and `ses_id` in order to find the subject data.

The code I'm using to open the file:

```
phaseBP = load_nifti([root_path '/BP_demeaned_0.033-0.07Hz_sub-' subj '_' 'ses-' ses_id '_task-rest_desc-preproc_bold-cropped.nii.gz']);
```

Running the code gives me this:

```
cd /media/megan2/VERBATIM HD

zcat /media/megan2/VERBATIM HD/dHCP_data/sub-CC00852XX11/ses-28210/func/BP_demeaned_0.033-0.07Hz_sub-CC00852XX11_ses-28210_task-rest_desc-preproc_bold-cropped.nii.gz > /tmp/tpb5ca9cf4_93fd_45f1_abdf_a96530646c80.load_nifti.m.nii

ERROR: gzip: /media/megan2/VERBATIM.gz: No such file or directory
gzip: HD/dHCP_data/sub-CC00852XX11/ses-28210/func/BP_demeaned_0.033-0.07Hz_sub-CC00852XX11_ses-28210_task-rest_desc-preproc_bold-cropped.nii.gz: No such file or directory
```

This just displays an empty 0x0 matrix in the workspace.

Things I've already tried:

- I've double checked to ensure that the desired .nii.gz file is within the mentioned directory.
- I've tested using the **readnifti** function to ensure that the data can be accessed that way - it can so MATLAB can find the data, but gives me an error when I try to use the **load_nifti** function ( which I have to use in this case since I need the structure from the data and it's headers (not an array which **readnifti** gives.
  I've ensure that I have set my directory correctly
- I've used the **load_nifti** function by directly searching for the file name: /media/megan2/VERBATIM HD/dHCP_data/sub-CC00852XX11/ses-28210/func/BP_demeaned_0.033-0.07Hz_sub-CC00852XX11_ses-28210_task-rest_desc-preproc_bold-cropped.nii.gz - which has given me the same result.

Comment: I don’t think there is a function with this name in any of the official MATLAB toolboxes. But I did find this 3rd party function, is this it? https://github.com/fieldtrip/fieldtrip/blob/master/external/freesurfer/load_nifti.m — please [edit] your post to clarify which function you use and where you got it from!

Comment: There is an official MATLAB function `niftiread`, did you try using that? https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/niftiread.html

Comment: From the error message, it seems that it’s tripping over the space character in the path (`VERBATIM HD`). Try renaming that volume, or moving the file elsewhere. Though likely the official MATLAB function will work correctly.

Comment: @CrisLuengo, it seems like that moving the file elsewhere was the solution. I had thought since the space character was present within the external storage drive (VERBATIM HD) for earlier functioning commands, it wouldn't be a problem. Moving the files into the main drive solves this issue. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You might need to unzip it first to get a .nii file and then read that with niftiread.

Comment: @Matt The function being called does exactly that, and it fails running the external command to unzip the file because the toolbox authors didn't put quotes around the file name when creating the shell command.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I meant manually unzipping your files to get them in .nii file format first before trying to call niftiread. I have successfully used niftiread to read .nii files before. I don't believe that directly reading gzipped .nii.gz files with niftiread is supported. I don't see anything in the documentation that suggests that reading compressed NIfTI files is supported.

Comment: @Matt Sorry, I misunderstood. But `niftiread` does support .nii.gz files. From the docs: "If `niftiread` cannot find a file with the `.nii` extension, then it looks for a gzipped version of the file, with extension `.nii.gz`."